# Common errors using OAuth and Spring when building microservices project

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, microservices

**Got stuck while using OAuth in my microservices Spring project**

Hello, I got stuck many times and decided to write a few obstacles I faced while doing my project, and actually posting this question helped me to solve some of them by just writing them down and analyzing the issues.

However, I still need some help so would really appreciate any feedback or suggestions:

Some abbreviations I use:

- Authorization Server = *A.S*

Issues I have faced:

1. Clients are not registered -- Solved
2. Not getting access token {"error" : "invalid_client"}  -- Solved
3. Account Service will send requests to Stats Service via Feign Client, so it is necessary to put in the request's headers the Access Token obtained from the Authorization Server. -- In progress

I have two microservices, Account-Service and Statistics-Service, called simply 'account' and 'stats' respectively, also there is a separate auth-service.

Here is the application.yml of each, (all of them stored in a separated config-server)

Here it is the Authorization Server:

SecurityConfig.java:

````
```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    //This is a custom security filter I made, not in the scope of the question so just ignore it, I'm not using it here
    @Autowired
    SecurityFilter securityFilter;


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(httpSecurity);
        httpSecurity.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                        new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/lg"),
                        new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                )
        )
                .oauth2ResourceServer( rs -> rs.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) //disable csrf
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults()) //using defined Bean CorsConfigurationSource
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)) //stateless session
                .headers( headers -> headers.frameOptions(fo -> fo.sameOrigin())) //allowing h2 to be displayed as a frame
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/clients").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("**"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

```
````

AuthConfig.java:

````
```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig  {

    //default auth-server settings
    @Bean
    AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }


    //in memory registered client repository
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository clientRepository() {

        RegisteredClient accountClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("account")
                //password encoded with BCrypt via Spring CLI, I do not include {bcrypt} since BCryptPasswordEncoder does not strip those characters.
                .clientSecret("$2a$10$TzT7IIecZntBHIgkqeAM/.wFNdidep8ZqGsjcCGP4dEKYjjeEGDeW")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .clientName("account")
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .build();
        RegisteredClient statsClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("stats")
                //password encoded with BCrypt via Spring CLI, I do not include {bcrypt} since BCryptPasswordEncoder does not strip those characters.
                .clientSecret("$2a$10$LPfixEzpQzLebNnkbDI1COiZFaD8MV3hCa36A5B8vmDJvv3UWkkCa")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .clientName("stats")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(accountClient, statsClient);
    }

    //token source
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }


}
```
````

Here it is the Account Security Config:

````
```@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                //allowing h2 to display in a frame of the same origin as our app
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(options -> options.sameOrigin()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers( "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/demo").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/demo").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAuthority(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())

                //Very simple Security Config, just indicating the type of tokens supported by our server here.
                .oauth2ResourceServer(rs -> rs.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }


}```
````

Here it is the Stats Security Config, very similar to the Account's configuration:

````
```@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(fop -> fop.sameOrigin()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/save").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(rs -> rs.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }
}
```
````

Solutions and what I have tried:

1. Tips for registering clients:

Make sure you use the correct order while writing your .properties or .yaml file, as in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html) :
spring>security>oauth2>authorizationserver>client>{yourClientId}>registration

I used to put registration before the {yourClientId} so it did not work.

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: user
      password: password
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          oidc-client:
            registration:
              client-id: "oidc-client"
              client-secret: "{noop}secret"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "authorization_code"
                - "refresh_token"
              redirect-uris:
                - "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client"
              post-logout-redirect-uris:
                - "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
              scopes:
                - "openid"
                - "profile"
            require-authorization-consent: true
```

2. **A tip if your are getting { "error" : "client_error" }
   In my case, the *A.S* uses an UserDetailsService that gets users from a Postgres database, which made me create a `@Bean` of `PasswordEncoder` for Authentication purposes. Then I had a little headache because I could not get the access token with Postman while testing if the *A.S* was working correctly.

I sent the `client_id` and `client_secret` in a Basic Auth header, which were "account" and "{noop}secret" respectively as you can see,  but I got `{"error":"invalid_client"}`... it turns out that my *A.S* was using the BCrypt PasswordEncoder that is supposed to be used only for the UserDetailsService, and I was entering "secret" as plain text, so the secret was invalid for the *A.S*.

I tried to explicitly configure the *A.S* to use `NoOpPasswordEncoder` for the purpose of testing it but without success. Anyway, I just started encrypting my passwords with Spring CLI before sending it in the request (whether with Postman or CURL) and it worked.

1. Download Spring CLI
2. use the command, `spring encodepassword <yourpassword>`
   the output will be something like {bcrypt}$2a$10$LPfixEzpQzLebNnkbDI1COiZFaD8MV3hCa36A5B8vmDJvv3UWkkCa
3. copy the result without the {bcrypt} portion and register your client with THAT secret
4. send a request whether with CURL and Postman using Basic Auth, it should work

auth.yaml

````
```
spring:
#decided to comment this configuration since I'm configuring the RegisteredClientRepository programatically
#  security:
#    oauth2:
#      authorization-server:
#        client:
#          account-client:
#            registration:
#              client-id: 'account-client'
#              client-secret: {noop}secret
#              client-authentication-methods:
#                - client_secret_basic
#              authorization-grant-types:
#                - authorization_code
#                - refresh_token
#              redirect-uris:
#                - "http://127.0.0.1:8083/api/account/login/oauth2/code/account-client"
#              post-logout-redirect-uris:
#                - "http://127.0.0.1:8083/api/account/"
#              scopes:
#                - "read"
#            require-authorization-consent: true


  datasource:
#    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
#    username: sa
#    password: password
#    url: jdbc:h2:mem:demo
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: pepeeselmejor
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
#  jpa:
#    hibernate:
#      ddl-auto: none
#    show-sql: true
#    defer-datasource-initialization: true
#    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#  h2:
#    console:
#      enabled: true

api:
  security:
    token:
      secret: ${JWT_SECRET:secret}
  issuer: ${JWT_ISSUER:myessen}
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: TRACE
management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
```
````

account.yaml

````
```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/account
  port: 8083

spring:
  profile: dev
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource-server:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:7099/api/auth
      client:
        provider:
          auth:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:7099/api/auth
        registration:
          account:
            provider: auth
            client-id: account
            client-secret: secret
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8083/api/account/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            scope: oidc.profile
            client-name: account
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:demo
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true


logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        jdbc:
          core:
            JdbcTemplate: DEBUG
            StatementCreatorUtils: TRACE
      hibernate:
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE
        SQL: DEBUG
```
````

stats.yaml

````
```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/stats
  port: 8085
spring:
  profile: dev
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource-server:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:7099/api/auth
#      client:
#        clientId: stat
#        clientSecret: password
#        accessTokenUri: http://localhost:7099/api/auth/oauth2/token
#        authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
#        scope: oidc.profile
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:demo
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: TRACE
```

Here is the pom.xml of each

auth service:
```
    <dependencies>
<!--        Web dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        Data dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
<!--        Spring security & auth0 JWT-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        Cloud dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--    Test dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.37.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

```
````

account service:

```
    <dependencies>
<!--        Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        Web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        Cloud-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        Databases-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        //test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

stats service:

````
<!--        data-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
<!--        security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        cloud-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>    
```
````

At this stage, I'm trying to make the Account Service send requests via FeignClient, I need to include the Access Token in the headers. Any suggestion is well received.

PD: Some suggestions about the yaml files are more than well received, it is a good practice to set the context-path to something like "api/{serviceName}" as I did?

Also, there should be a way in which I can use something like resourceserver.jwt.issuer=http://auth-service:7099 instead of hardcoding the host? that's the idea behind a microservice architecture orchestrated with Eureka Netlix